# Error: "Uncompilable source code"

Tags: java, swing, this, jcombobox, runtimeexception

I am in the preliminary stages and can't seem to get the program to run regardless of what I try.  I think the issue has something to do with how I am calling the keyword "this" but I can't be sure.

For now I have the program simply printing out what is highlighted in the JComboBox in order to keep it simple being that the comparison aspect can be done simply later using "if" statements.  Any help is appreciated.  Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    JFrame frame;
    JPanel panel;
    JLabel label1;
    JLabel label2;

    public Main() {
        super(new BorderLayout());

        String[] colorStrings = { "", "Black", "White", "Red", "Blue", "Yellow",
        "Green", "Orange", "Purple"};
        JComboBox color1 = new JComboBox(colorStrings);
        color1.setSelectedIndex(7);
        color1.addActionListener(this);
        JComboBox color2 = new JComboBox(colorStrings);
        color2.setSelectedIndex(7);
        color2.addActionListener(this);

        add(label1, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        add(color1, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        add(label2, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        add(color2, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20,20,20,20));
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JComboBox listen1 = (JComboBox)e.getSource();
        String otherColor1 = (String)listen1.getSelectedItem();
        System.out.println(otherColor1);
        JComboBox listen2 = (JComboBox)e.getSource();
        String otherColor2 = (String)listen2.getSelectedItem();
        System.out.println(otherColor2);
    }
    private static void createAndShowGUI(JComboBox color1, JComboBox color2) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Does it match?");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JComponent newContentPane = new Main();
        newContentPane.add(color1, color2);
        newContentPane.setOpaque(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI();
        }
    });
} 
}
```

The error that shows up is:

> run:
>   Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: createAndShowGUI
>       at Main$1.run(Main.java:53)
>       at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:727)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:686)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:697)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
>   BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 3 seconds)

Comment: What is a "JObjectBox"?? Never heard of that animal. Please only use real class names in your questions to avoid confusion.

Comment: What do you mean *"can't seem to get the program to run regardless"*?

Comment: The program will not run as is.

Comment: `"The program will not run as is."` -- So when you try to run it, you get an error? If so, then please show us the error.

Comment: JComboBox**  What do you mean by real class names?

Comment: You mention JObjectBox, and that class doesn't exist, it's not real.

Comment: I have now included the error.

Comment: Chit, you're trying to run code that you can't compile. Never do that. First compile it, get the compilation error, and fix that before trying to run it.

Answer (score 4):

1. `createAndShowGUI` is expecting two parameters, but in your `main` method you are passing none.  I can't see why you actually need them as you creating them in the `Main` class anyway...
2. You create an instance of `Main` called `newContentPane` but never actually add it to anything...
3. You are adding `label1` and `label2` to the same position within the `BorderLayout`, effectively hiding `label1`
4. You are adding `color1` and `color2` to the same position within the `BorderLayout`, effectively hiding `color1`
5. You never insansiate `label1` or `label2` leading to a `NullPointerException`

Also, you `actionListener` logic is wrong...

```
JComboBox listen1 = (JComboBox) e.getSource();
String otherColor1 = (String) listen1.getSelectedItem();
System.out.println(otherColor1);
JComboBox listen2 = (JComboBox) e.getSource();
String otherColor2 = (String) listen2.getSelectedItem();
```

`listen1` and `listen2` are the same thing...

### Working Example

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Main extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    JFrame frame;
    JPanel panel;
    JLabel label1;
    JLabel label2;

    public Main() {
        // Change the layout to something more useful
        super(new GridLayout(2, 2));

        String[] colorStrings = {"", "Black", "White", "Red", "Blue", "Yellow",
            "Green", "Orange", "Purple"};
        JComboBox color1 = new JComboBox(colorStrings);
        color1.setSelectedIndex(7);
        color1.addActionListener(this);
        JComboBox color2 = new JComboBox(colorStrings);
        color2.setSelectedIndex(7);
        color2.addActionListener(this);

        // Create the instances of the labels to prevent NullPointerException
        label1 = new JLabel("#1");
        label2 = new JLabel("#2");

        add(label1);
        add(color1);
        add(label2);
        add(color2);
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20, 20, 20, 20));
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JComboBox listen1 = (JComboBox) e.getSource();
        String otherColor1 = (String) listen1.getSelectedItem();
        System.out.println(otherColor1);
        JComboBox listen2 = (JComboBox) e.getSource();
        String otherColor2 = (String) listen2.getSelectedItem();
        System.out.println(otherColor2);
    }

    // This doesn't make sense
//    private static void createAndShowGUI(JComboBox color1, JComboBox color2) {
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Does it match?");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JComponent newContentPane = new Main();
        // Actually add the Main to the frame...
        frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // This will now work
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: You may be a bit too helpful here. 1+. i.e., spoon feeding.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Avoiding the inevitable "how do I fix it" comment :P

Comment: I don't know. I think that we learn by struggling a bit. He really needs to first learn how to compile code and fix compilation errors more than he needs a running version of his problem.

Comment: I agree with you as well, that is why I just went through and traced every line of this program until I understood what I did wrong and how it was corrected.